# PHP file download problem: Server freezes for several minutes when user cancels a download then retries

Tags: php, download

I'm using the following the PHP script to download a 20mb file:

(filepath & filename are set earlier in the script)

```
$fullPath = $filepath.$filename;

if ($fd = fopen($fullPath, "r")) {  
        // http headers for zip downloads
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($fullPath));
            while(!feof($fd)) {
            echo(fread($fd, 1024*8));
            flush();
            if (connection_status()!=0) {
                fclose($fd);
                die();
            }
        }
    }
fclose($fd);
exit();
```

It works fine if the download finishes, but if the download is canceled by the user, and they click on the link to re-download, the server is completely unresponsive for several minutes, and then the download will begin. It seems like it is waiting for the script to time out...but isn't the "if (connection_status()!=0)..." part supposed to kil the script?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: use readfile instead @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: Doesn't [`ignore_user_abort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) have to be used in tandem with `connection_status`?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're over-engineering your solution somewhat.  Try using readfile() instead of your fopen/fread loop.

Better yet, unless there's a compelling reason why you need PHP to mediate the file transfer, don't use a PHP script at all and simply provide a direct link to the file in question.

The best code is always the code you don't have to write.